# Limit $\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}(\sum_{s=1990}^t (1-\delta)^{t-s}*I_{is})+\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}(1-\delta)^{t-s}*K_{i,1990}$

Tags: limits

Can somebody help me with this:

$$\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}(\sum_{s=1990}^t (1-\delta)^{t-s}*I_{is})+\lim_{t\rightarrow \infty}(1-\delta)^{t-1990}*K_{i,1990}$$

$$\delta\in(0,1)$$

I'd say the right side goes towards 0. I am not sure about the left side...

Thanks

Comment: What are $I_{is}$ and $K_{I,19909,}$?

Comment: Sorry, Assume that they are constants

Comment: The second term contains $s$, which is the same designation as the "dummy" summation index.  Are you certain that you've written the expression correctly, or is the double use of $s$ coincidental only?

Comment: Sorry again, my bad. I  have corrected it. I am still learning to use Mathjax...

Comment: You can't say anything about the first limit without knowing something about the numbers $I_{is}$.  Do you have any constraints on them?

Comment: Not that I know of. I stands for Investments, while K stands for Capital Stock. 
Can't I take I infront of Sigma?

Answer (score 0):

The first limit can take any value at all (or fail to exist), if you have no constraints on the numbers $I_{is}$.  Let's write $$X_t=\sum_{1990}^t(1-\delta)^{t-s}I_{is}.$$  Notice that 
\begin{align*}X_{t+1}&=\sum_{1990}^{t+1}(1-\delta)^{t+1-s}I_{is}\\
&=I_{i(t+1)}+\sum_{1990}^t(1-\delta)(1-\delta)^{t-s}I_{is}\\
&=I_{i(t+1)}+(1-\delta)X_t.
\end{align*}

This means that, given the numbers $I_{is}$ for $s\leq t$, it is possible to choose $I_{i(t+1)}$ so that $X_{t+1}$ has any value at all: if you want $X_{t+1}$ to be some number $x$, just take $I_{i(t+1)}=x-(1-\delta)X_t$ (the value of $X_t$ is determined by the numbers $I_{is}$ for $s\leq t$).  So it is possible for the sequence $(X_t)$ to be any sequence of numbers at all.  In particular, it could have any limit, or the limit could not exist.

Comment: Hi Eric

What would the answer be if we leave out I from the equation?

Thanks

Comment: Then you would get a geometric series with limit $1/\delta$ (since writing the terms in reverse order, $X_t$ is just $1+(1-\delta)+(1-\delta)^2+\dots+(1-\delta)^{t-1990}$.)

Comment: Thank you Eric, that solved my problem!